# AutoIncrement key in DynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is there a way to generate an autoincrement value for a non-Primary Key in AWS DynamoDB.
My requirement is to create a column named 'Display_Order' which will have an autoincremented value by the DB itself as new items are inserted using java.

Comment: This is RDBMS thinking. In DDB (and other scaleable NoSQL DB) you don't want to have the keys in order. It can create issues when you are trying to insert from multiple clients in parallel, for example. Simply hash your key or any other way to keep it unique.

Comment: @Guy - Okie I am having a hash key which is my primary key. But I need to display my data in the order of insertion because of which I want an autoincrement nonprimary key.

Comment: sort by update-time or some other timestamp

Answer (score 2):

DynamoDB natively does not support the auto-increment feature. It has to be implemented at the application level.

One way it can be implemented is having a different Dynamo table for storing this meta-information and referring that table for the latest value and then increment the value in meta table.

Now DynamoDB supports transactions, so you can also use them in the updates to avoid any race conditions.

Answer (score 2):

There is no auto-increment key for dynamodb, but for your use case you could get by with adding a field for 'createdate', and store the time, possibly in milliseconds, that the row was inserted and that would serve your purpose of allowing the results to be sorted in the order you want, i.e. by the order in which the objects were inserted.